# В MVC5 не работает wizard и jquery.bootstrap.wizard

Tags: jquery, mvc

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <title>Bootstrap Wizard by Creative Tim</title>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/favicon.ico">    

    <link href="~/Content/gsdk-base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>*@
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/wizard.js"></script>
    <!--   plugins   -->

    <!--  More information about jquery.validate here: http://jqueryvalidation.org/  -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

    <!--  methods for manipulating the wizard and the validation -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/wizard.js"></script>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <!--      Wizard container        -->
            <div class="wizard-container">
                <div class="card wizard-card ct-wizard-green" id="wizard">
                    <form action="" method="">
                        <div class="wizard-header">
                            <!--<h3>
                                <b>LIST</b> YOUR PLACE <br>
                                <small>This information will let us know more about your place.</small>
                            </h3>-->
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="active" style="width:25%"><a href="#ish" data-toggle="tab">İş <br />haqqında</a></li>
                            <li style="width:25%"><a href="#account" data-toggle="tab">Öz məlumatınızı<br /> daxil edin</a></li>
                            <li style="width:25%"><a href="#pris" data-toggle="tab">Qiyməti və <br />ödənişi seçin</a></li>
                            <li style="width:25%"><a href="#icra" data-toggle="tab">İcraçını <br />seçin</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane active" id="ish">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <!--<div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <h4 class="info-text"> Let's start with the basic details</h4>
                                        </div>-->
                                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Kateqoriya</label><br>
                                            <select name="categorya" class="form-control">
                                                <option disabled="" selected="">  </option>
                                                <option>1 Person</option>
                                                <option>2 Persons </option>
                                                <option>3 Persons</option>
                                                <option>4 Persons</option>
                                                <option>5 Persons</option>
                                                <option>6+ Persons</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Numune</label>
                                            <p class="description">"Siz formanı doldurandan bir neçə dəq sonra maraqlananlar müraciət edəcək"</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>İş haqqında(qısa):</label>
                                            <input id="ish_sm" name="ish_sm" placeholder="İş haqqında qısa..." class="form-control" type="text" autofocus="true">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5 ">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>İş haqqında(Ətraflı):</label>
                                            <textarea id="ish_lg" class="form-control" placeholder="İş haqqında geniş..." rows="2"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Nə vaxta lazımdır:</label>
                                            <input id="tarix" name="tarix" placeholder="Tarix..." class="form-control" type="datetime-local" autofocus="true"><!--required="required"-->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane" id="account">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Adı:<small></small></label><!--(required)-->
                                            <input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" placeholder="Adı..." class="form-control" type="text" autofocus="true">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Soy-adı</label>
                                            <input id="LastName" name="LastName" placeholder="Soy-adı..." class="form-control" type="text" autofocus="true">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Email<small></small></label><!--(required)-->
                                            <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="xx@xx.xx ..." class="form-control" type="email" autofocus="true">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Telefon:</label>
                                            <input id="Phone" name="Phone" placeholder="Telefon..." class="form-control" type="text" autofocus="true">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Unvan:</label><br>
                                            <select name="country" class="form-control">
                                                <option value="Afghanistan"> Afghanistan </option>
                                                <option value="Albania"> Albania </option>
                                                <option value="Algeria"> Algeria </option>
                                                <option value="American Samoa"> American Samoa </option>
                                                <option value="Andorra"> Andorra </option>
                                                <option value="Angola"> Angola </option>
                                                <option value="Anguilla"> Anguilla </option>
                                                <option value="Antarctica"> Antarctica </option>
                                                <option value="...">...</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5 ">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>.</label><br>
                                            <input id="Unvan_1" name="Phone" placeholder="Unvan..." class="form-control" type="text" autofocus="true">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Password </label>
                                            <input id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-control" type="password" autofocus="true">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5 ">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>ConfirmPassword <small>(required)</small></label>
                                            <input id="ConfirmPassword" name="ConfirmPassword" placeholder="ConfirmPassword..." class="form-control" type="password" autofocus="true">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                                        <div class="picture-container">
                                            <div class="picture">
                                                <img src="../Content/img/default-avatar.png" class="picture-src" id="wizardPicturePreview" title="">
                                                <input type="file" id="wizard-picture">
                                            </div>
                                            <h6>Choose Picture</h6>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane" id="pris">
                                <!--<h4 class="info-text">Tell us more about facilities. </h4>-->
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Qiyməti daxil edin</label>
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rent price per day">-->
                                                <input id="qiymet" name="qiymet" value="" placeholder="qiymet..." class="form-control" type="number" required="required" autofocus="true">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">(manat)</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Numune</label>
                                            <p class="description">"Proqram icraçını sizin yerinizə avtomatik olaraq seçə bilər və ya siz özünüz seçə bilərsiniz. "</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                                        <div data-toggle="wizard-checkbox">
                                            <input type="radio" name="icra" value="1" required="required" checked="checked">
                                            <div class="icon">
                                                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <h6>Avtomatik</h6>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                                        <div data-toggle="wizard-checkbox">
                                            <input type="radio" name="icra" value="2" required="required">
                                            <div class="icon">
                                            </div>
                                            <h6>Özünüz</h6>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane" id="icra">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <h4 class="info-text"> Drop us a small description. </h4>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Place description</label>
                                            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="" rows="4"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Example</label>
                                            <p class="description">"The place is really nice. We use it every sunday when we go fishing. It is so awesome."</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wizard-footer">
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <input type='button' class='btn btn-next btn-fill btn-success btn-wd btn-sm' name='next' value='Next' />
                                <input type='button' class='btn btn-finish btn-fill btn-success btn-wd btn-sm' name='finish' value='Finish' />

                            </div>
                            <div class="pull-left">
                                <input type='button' class='btn btn-previous btn-fill btn-default btn-wd btn-sm' name='previous' value='Previous' />
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- wizard container -->
        </div>
    </div> <!-- row -->
</div> <!--  big container -->
```

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса так как он не на русском языке